# Sorting a gridview control - The direction never changes

Tags: c#, gridview, code-behind

I can't seem to get this right, even after looking at a few examples.

I've got this code, which happily re-sorts my gridview in an Ascending order:

```
    // gridViewSorting and ConvertSortDirectionToSql are both necessary to ensure the gridview can sort when their column headers are
    //   clicked.  You must remember to add (AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridViewSorting") to the gridview tag on the ASP side
    protected void gridViewSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
       DataTable dataTable = GVInactive.DataSource as DataTable;

       if (dataTable != null)
       {
          DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
          string SQL = "[" + e.SortExpression + "] " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
          dataView.Sort = SQL;

          GVInactive.DataSource = dataView.ToTable();
          GVInactive.DataBind();

       }
    }

    private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                newSortDirection = "DESC";
                break;

            case SortDirection.Descending:
                newSortDirection = "ASC";
                break;
        }

        return newSortDirection;
    }
```

However, the second time I click on the header it's supposed to reverse the previous sorting order.  It never does.  Every time I click the header of a column, it hits the `case SortDirection.Ascending:` line and sets newSortDirection = "DESC".  The data is sorted in descending order, yet when I click the header again it resolves SortDirection to Ascending.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We use a ViewState variable to store the latest Sort Direction. When the grid is sorted we compare the Sort Criteria and Sort Direction of the grid with the ViewState variables which stores last sort expression. If the columns are equal then check the direction of the previous sort and sort in the opposite direction.

Example:

```
    private string SortCriteria
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortCriteria"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["sortCriteria"] = "";
            }

            return ViewState["sortCriteria"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["sortCriteria"] = value;
        }
    }

    private string SortDirection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = "";
            }

            return ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void gvData_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        gvData.EditIndex = -1;

        if (SortCriteria == e.SortExpression)
        {
            if (SortDirection == string.Empty || SortDirection == "DESC") { SortDirection = "ASC"; }
            else { SortDirection = "DESC"; }
        }
        else
        {
            SortCriteria = e.SortExpression;
            SortDirection = "ASC";
        }

        BindGrid();
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new [However you get dataset from database];
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", SortCriteria, SortDirection).Trim();

        gvData.DataSource = dv;
        gvData.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like BindGrid() is a function.  Can you post that function as well; without it I only have half an answer.  Also, do I need any special references for this to work?

Comment: Good point. I have now dded the BindGrid method, which shows the use of the SortCriteria and SortDirection properties. Sorry for the oversight.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I replaced the code used in my question with this, and it worked **perfectly**:

```
    // gridViewSorting and ConvertSortDirectionToSql are both necessary to ensure the gridview can sort when their column headers are
    //   clicked.  You must remember to add (AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridViewSorting") to the gridview tag on the ASP side
    protected void gridViewSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = GVInactive.DataSource as DataTable;
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression; 
        string direction = string.Empty;

        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

            if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending) 
            { 
                SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending; 
                direction = " DESC"; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending; 
                direction = " ASC"; 
            }

            DataTable table = GVInactive.DataSource as DataTable;
            table.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

            GVInactive.DataSource = table;
            GVInactive.DataBind();

        }
    }

    public SortDirection SortDirection 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            if (ViewState["SortDirection"] == null) 
            { 
                ViewState["SortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending; 
            } 
            return (SortDirection)ViewState["SortDirection"]; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            ViewState["SortDirection"] = value; 
        } 
    }
```

I can probably remove a few lines (not sure I even need the DataView anymore), but it works perfectly as is.  Just remember to add these pieces to the ASP side in the GridView tag:

> AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridViewSorting"

and then change your gridview's name where appropriate.